# How to copy files with a specific pattern?

Tags: batch-file

I have some folders that contain at least one zip-file. However there could also be more zip-files in it. The folders look something like this:

```
parent
|
+--X7G000738512
|  |
|  `--X7G000738512_20141028_1210.zip
|
+--X7G000843295
|  |
|  +--X7G000843295_20141028_1210.zip
|  |
|  `--X7G000843295_20141028_1210_OLD.zip
|
+--X7G000482756
|  |
|  +--X7G000482756_20141028_1210.zip
|  |
|  `--X7G000482756_20141028_1210_ungueltig.zip
|
`--X7G000285672
   |
   +--X7G000285672_20141028_1210.zip
   |
   +--X7G000285672_20141028_1210_OLD.zip
   |
   `--X7G000285672_20141028_1210_ungueltig.zip
```

Now I want to copy the zip-files that don't end with "_OLD" or "_ungueltig" to the parent directory. How can i accomplish this task?

Comment: are you allowed to use Python? I know that you tagged it with batch file, but just checking. Alternatively, you can read [this](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) and to FOR loop through all your files and copy selective ones

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm limited to batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "target=c:\somewhere\parent"

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        dir /s /b /a-d "%target%\*.zip"
        ^| findstr /r /i /c:"%target:\=\\%\\[^\\]*\\.*"
        ^| findstr /l /v /i /e /c:"_OLD.zip" /c:"_ungueltig.zip"
    ') do for %%b in ("%%~dpa\..") do (
        copy "%%~a" "%%~fb"
    )
```

This uses a `dir` command to retrieve the full list of zip files, that is filtered with `findstr` to only process files under a subdirectory (not process files in target folder), and the remaining list is filtered to only process files that does not contain the indicated strings. The `for %%a` command processes this list of files, and for each one, a `copy` command is executed.

I was not sure about the `parent` in the question, so, in this code the `parent` is determined from the folder where the `.zip` file is stored. This is the reason for the `for %%b`, to determine the place where to copy the file.

If the `parent` folder is the `%target%` folder, remove the last `for` and  use

```
....
    ^| findstr /l /v /i /e /c:"_OLD.zip" /c:"_ungueltig.zip"
') do copy "%%~a" "%target%"
```